# Assembly Language with No Output Due to Counter

Tags: assembly, x86, output, irvine32

I've been trying to make a code in assembly that resembles a gradebook but I don't get any output and no errors. Does anyone know why there is nothing displayed to the screen?

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc


Student STRUCT
    myName BYTE 26 DUP(00h)
    myGrade BYTE 26 DUP(00h)
Student ENDS


.data
myClass Student 20 DUP(<>)
myNumber BYTE 3 DUP(00h)
nameQuestion BYTE "What is your name?",0dh,0ah,0
gradeQuestion BYTE "Please enter ",0
grade2Question BYTE "'s grade.",0dh,0ah,0
myName BYTE 26 DUP(00h)
myGrade BYTE 26 DUP(00h)
linebreak BYTE 0dh,0ah,0
comma BYTE ","
space BYTE " "
counter BYTE 0
.code
main PROC

R1: call Clrscr

    mov edx,OFFSET nameQuestion
    call WriteString

    mov edx,OFFSET myName
    mov ECX,26

    mov eax, SIZEOF Student
    mul myNumber
    mov esi,eax
    lea edx, (Student PTR myClass[esi]).myName 

    call ReadString

    cmp eax, 00h
    JE R2
    call Clrscr


R3: mov edx,OFFSET gradeQuestion
    call WriteString

    mov edx,OFFSET myName
    call WriteString

    mov edx,OFFSET grade2Question
    call WriteString

    mov edx,OFFSET myGrade
    mov ECX,26

    mov eax, SIZEOF Student
    mul myNumber
    mov esi,eax
    lea edx, (Student PTR myClass[esi]).myGrade

    call ReadString
    inc myNumber

L1: CMP myGrade, "A"
    JE R5
    CMP myGrade, "B"
    JE R5
    CMP myGrade, "C"
    JE R5
    CMP myGrade, "D"
    JE R5
    CMP myGrade, "F"
    JE R5
R5: inc counter
    CMP counter,20
    JNE R1  

R4: call Clrscr


L2: mov dh,3
    mov dl,5
    call Gotoxy
    inc dh

    mov eax, SIZEOF myClass
    mul counter
    mov esi, eax
    lea edx, (Student PTR myClass[esi]).myName
    call WriteString


J1: mov eax, 07h
    CMP myGrade, "D"
    JNE J2
    mov eax, 0Eh
J2: CMP myGrade, "F"
    JNE J3
    mov eax, 04h
J3: Call SetTextColor

    mov dh,3
    mov dl,32
    call Gotoxy
    inc dh

    mov eax, SIZEOF myClass
    mul counter
    mov esi, eax
    lea edx, (Student PTR myClass[esi]).myGrade
    call WriteString

    inc counter
    cmp counter, 20
    JB L2

    mov edx, OFFSET linebreak
    call WriteString

    mov eax, 07h
    Call SetTextColor

    call WaitMsg
    jmp R1
R2: exit
main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: In your repost of this ([Assembly Language taking data out of Structure and displaying it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53806799)), you seem to be saying the `mov edx,OFFSET nameQuestion` / `call WriteString` at the top of `main` *does* produce output?  That's not what you said here.  You said the whole program doesn't produce *any* output at all.  (Which would have indicated some kind of problem with your dev setup, and this is not a [mcve] of it: not even close to minimal.  That's why I downvoted).  If you have new info to add, edit your question instead of reposting.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mov edx,OFFSET myName
> mov ECX,26
>
> mov eax, SIZEOF Student
> mul myNumber
> mov esi,eax
> lea edx, (Student PTR myClass[esi]).myName 
>
> call ReadString
> ```

You're inputting directly in one of the 20 array elements, but later your code will rely on the non-existing content from the single *myName* buffer.
The same happens with the  non-existing content from the single *myGrade* buffer.
I suggest you input in the single buffers and then copy the contents to the relevant array elements. Together with this copying you could consider validating, trimming, capitalizing, and so on.

All of those different compares of the grade will always end up in the *R5* label no matter the outcome. The top part of your program therefore will always loop 20 times, leaving `counter=20`.

---

In the second part of your program you display all the strings on top of each other, since you place the cursor at a fixed position each time over! This fixed position must be chosen outside the loop.

Perhaps a bit luckily you don't see this happening since *counter* started at 20, meaning  `cmp counter, 20` `JB L2` will never repeat here!

---

> Does anyone know why there is nothing displayed to the screen?

I'm going with the assumption that inputting did show itself on the screen, but that **showing the final results doesn't produce anything on screen**.

Apart from what I already said above about *counter* erroneously starting at 20, there's one more reasons for that:

```
mov eax, SIZEOF myClass
mul counter
```

The calculation for your string addresses is wrong because you used `SIZEOF myClass` where you need `SIZEOF Student`.

---

Resetting *counter* and introducing an extra variable *row*:

```
    mov     counter, 0
    mov     row, 3

L2:
    mov     dh, row
    mov     dl, 5
    call    Gotoxy
    mov     eax, SIZEOF Student
    mul     counter

    ... display Student.myName

    mov     dh, row
    mov     dl, 32
    call    Gotoxy
    mov     eax, SIZEOF Student
    mul     counter

    ... display Student.myGrade

    inc     row
    inc     counter
    cmp     counter, 20
    JB      L2
```

Comment: `imul esi, [myNumber], SIZEOF Student` would be even better, if you're going to suggest an optimization.  Unlike most instructions, [imul-immediate has two other operands](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/IMUL.html), a separate dst and src, because it doesn't take over the `/r` field of the ModRM byte for extra opcode bits.  Writing it as a 2-operand instruction is supported by most assemblers, using src=dst.

Comment: Are you sure MASM assembles `mul myNumber` to DWORD operand-size?  The symbol was defined in terms of `BYTE`, so why isn't it `mul byte ptr [myNumber]`?   There's nothing that could imply DWORD.  (But IDK how that could cause a problem, because the upper bytes of EAX should already be zero from the `mov eax, SIZEOF Student`.)  This still looks like a bug, but unless I'm missing something and it does assemble with DWORD size, it probably doesn't actually cause an error other than wrapping at 64kiB offsets.